# ios - UItoolbar with items out of bounds

Tags: ios, toolbar, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UItoolbar and init, I have subviews which are a bit out of toolbar frame. When I click them in area which is not in toolbar frame, the UITapGestureRecognizer is not working. Is there some possibility to do it work? Here is image of my toolbar:

[image]

**EDIT**

code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *koleckoTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addFell:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *scoreTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
UITapGestureRecognizer *likesTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];


UIImageView *scoreView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-90, -25, 60, 60)];
scoreView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"score"];
scoreView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[scoreView addGestureRecognizer:scoreTap];
scoreView.tag = 55885588856;
scoreView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

UIImageView *likesView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)+30, -25, 60, 60)];
likesView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"likes"];
likesView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[likesView addGestureRecognizer:likesTap];
likesView.tag = 55885588856;

UIImageView *mainView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-40, -45, 80, 80)];
mainView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kolecko"];
mainView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[mainView addGestureRecognizer:koleckoTap];
mainView.tag = 55885588856;
mainView.clipsToBounds = YES;
mainView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

//self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:33.0 / 255.0 green:157.0 / 255.0 blue:147.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]];

[self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pruhledny.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
//self.toolbarItems=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,koleckoBar,flexibleSpace,nil];
[self.navigationController.toolbar insertSubview:scoreView atIndex:1];
[self.navigationController.toolbar insertSubview:likesView atIndex:2];
[self.navigationController.toolbar insertSubview:mainView atIndex:3];
```

Comment: I think set clipsubviews to NO will work.

Comment: Provide your codes will be more useful

Comment: Rahul: Where and to what should I set that pls?

Comment: Check the subview hierarchy.